# Merging gtk subpixbufs

Tags: python, gtk, gdkpixbuf

I'm presently playing with gtk.pixbuf in python. In the API, the subpixbuf function is described as returning a pixbuf that shares data with the original pixbuf :

> The subpixbuf() method creates a new gtk.gdk.Pixbuf that represents a sub-region of the pixbuf. The new pixbuf shares its pixels with the original pixbuf, so writing to one affects both.

But...

when I'm trying to divide a pixbuf in a list of subpixbuf and assign a value to each item, the original pixbuf stays the same.

```
animation.subpixbuf=[]
animation.pixbuf.fill(self.LIGHT_SQ_COLOR)
for i in range(64) :
   animation.subpixbuf += [animation.pixbuf.subpixbuf((7-i%8)*self.sq_width (i/8)*self.sq_width,w,w)]
   animation.subpixbuf[i]=self.squares[63-i]
```

Any ideas on how to compose a pixbuf from a bunch of subpixbufs ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `animation.subpixbuf[i]=self.squares[63-i]`, you're assigning `subpixbuf[i]` to a new Pixbuf object. You're not changing the Pixbuf previously stored in `subpixbuf[i]`.

To do what you want to do you should take a look at the `copy_area` method of the Pixbuf class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting me back on tracks. I can't believe I missed that one ! I was on another solution using a pixmap but yours sounds much better and straight forward. I'll definitely use it !